# Making a number sequence of n natural numbers

Tags: c

This code here stores first n natural number. And the order of number is ascending. Now we have to print all the number so that `a[i]` must not be divisible by `a[j]` where `i>j`. 
Here is the simple code I have written. I tried doing in O(n) order using one loop. 
But it is giving garbage value.

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int i=1,n;
    printf("enter the numbers \n");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    int a[n];
    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
    {
        a[i]=i;
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    while(a[i+1]>a[i] && a[i+1]%a[i]!=0){
        printf("%d",a[i]);
        i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In C array are from `0` to `n-1`. Also you forget to reset the value of `i` before entering the while loop.

Comment: @user2456752 may be because of array indexing in while condition. Check that if you are not makes out of bound error.

Answer (score 2):

Use `malloc` to allocate memory of `n` ints:

```
int *a = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * n); //and check that allocation has succeed
```

Then, don't forget that arrays are *zero-based* in C. So your loop should be:

```
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
```

And before entering the `while` loop, make sure to reset `i` and that `i + 1` doesn't exceed the arrays limit.

Comment: Is there any particular reason of using malloc and declaring it a pointer?

Comment: @user2456752 yes because variable size array is not viable in standard C (I mean old C), I think it came with c99. So I will always prefer malloc instead of variable length arrays declaration. But remember memory allocated using malloc/calloc should be explicitly deallocated using `free();` Read here: [Variable-length array](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array)

Comment: You should also mention that casting the result of malloc is unnecessary :)

Comment: @PHIfounder I don't add this comment till user cast correctly, for the same reason portability with c++.

Answer (score 0):

Bugs:

1) Check the value of `i` when the `while` loop is entered - that's for the "garbage" you are talking about.

2) `n` is uninitialized. You are using it in allocating the array.

3) arrays are zero-based. So in the for loop, should be  `i=0;i<n`

4) while loop does not care about whether `i` (or `i+1`) is `<n`. Potentially a problem.

As for the functionality of your code, it does not implement what you describe. But SO is not a coding service, and it will be good for cultivating your programming skills that you do it yourself - first, take just a pen and paper and think about the program flow.

HTH.

Comment: i=0;
while( i+1<n && a[i+1]>a[i] && a[i+1]%a[i]!=0)
giving i =0 before the loop starts and changing the while loop condition to above given don't work either .

Comment: You mean, the code crashes, or it does not do what you want? I was writing about how to make the code sane at the first place, and I made a note about what I would recommend if you want the code to do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

When entering while loop, please make `i=0`.